# Stopping Mouse Events In EaselJS

Tags: javascript, createjs, easeljs

What is the best way to prevent an event handler from being fired in easelJS? In other projects I would use e.stopPropagation but that doesn't seem to work in easelJS.

The issue is that I am working with a library that uses easelJS and has a "pressmove" event handler to enable drag and drop. I'd  like to prevent this handler from being fired if a modifier key, like ctrl or shift, is being held when the event is triggered. After checking whether a modifier is being held I would ideally then be able to trigger the original pressmove handler if need be.

Answer (score 1):

The `stopPropagation` method prevents an event from being bubbled, not fired. You can use `stopImmediatePropagation` to prevent other listeners at the same level from receiving the event *after* you (behaviour will depend on the order of events).

Ideally if you have a condition where you want to prevent a behavior, then look that up in your event handler, and conditionally handle the behaviour.

```
obj.on("pressmove", function(e) {
  if (someCondition) {
    doSomething();
  }
});
```

You can also toggle `mouseEnabled` to prevent an object from responding to mouse events (and `mouseChildren` if you want to block events on children of a container).

```
obj.mouseEnabled = false;
```

Hope that helps.